# Regex not accepting numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I can't figure out why this regex pattern isn't accepting numbers? It used to but then I added [()#'/- part and it stopped.

```
^[()#'/-0-9A-Za-z ]+$
```

Comment: Escape 1st `-`: `^[()#'/\-0-9A-Za-z ]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/-0` created a valid range that only matches `/` or `0`:

[image]

So, your regex could match a string with `0` and `9` in it (like [`()#'/0-9ABCZab c`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%28%29%23%27%2f-0-9A-Za-z+%5d%2b%24&i=%28%29%23%27%2f0-9ABCZabc+)), but not the whole digit range.

Replace with

```
^[-()#'/0-9A-Za-z ]+$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B-%28%29%23%27%2F0-9A-Za-z%20%5D%2B%24&i=Abc1233-%28%29%23%27%2F%20z)

Answer (score 1):

Take "-" out before "0"

```
^[()#'/0-9A-Za-z ]+$
```